# Vue3. Error occurs when redirecting to 404 page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a JSON file that stores data for a card. Inside this file, there is an `alias` key where I write down the path of the page to which I need to go if there is such an object in the JSON file.

Next, I want to create a card component that will receive an array element from the JSON along the route, check if there is such an element in the data file, and if so, take this data and substitute it in the template, thereby rendering the page. But if there is no such data, I want to redirect to a 404 page. When I enter a non-existent address, I do not get a redirect, but instead, an error occurs in the browser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt3jA.jpg

It seems that when the redirect occurs, my component does not stop its rendering but tries to draw further. I want it to go to another page and stop its execution. I do not understand why this is happening, and what is my mistake here?

Below is the code that I have:

`items.json`

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "alias": "barbarian",
    "title": "The Barbarian",
    "desc": "The Barbarian is a kilt-clad Scottish warrior with an angry, battle-ready expression, hungry for destruction. He has a killer yellow horseshoe mustache.",
    "img": "barbarian.png",
    "lvl": 4,
    "info": [
      {
        "title": "training",
        "value": "20s"
      },
      {
        "title": "speed",
        "value": "16"
      },
      {
        "title": "cost",
        "value": "150"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

`routes.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "HomePage",
      component: () => import("@/views/Home.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "AboutPage",
      component: () => import("@/views/About.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/items/:itemAlias",
      name: "itemAlias",
      component: () => import("@/views/Card.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
      name: "404",
      component: () => import("@/views/404.vue")
    }
  ]
});

export default router;
```

`Card.vue`

```js
<template lang="pug">
  .wrapper-personal
    h1.title.title--white {{ item.title }}
    p(style="max-width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;") {{ item.desc }}
    card-stats(:stats="item.info")
    router-link.btn.btnDefault(to="/") Back to Home
</template>

<script>
import items from "@/mocks/items.json";
import CardStats from "@/modules/card/CardStats.vue";

export default {
  name: "CardItem",
  components: {
    CardStats
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: null
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const alias = this.$route.params.itemAlias;
    const item = items.find(el => el.alias === alias);

    if (!item) {
      await this.$router.push({ name: "404" });
      return;
    }

    this.item = item;
  }
};
</script>
```

If you require additional information, I am happy to provide it.